# Should FirstOrDefault(lambda) and Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault() work the same?

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I was under the impression `FirstOrDefault(lambda)` had the same effect on a collection as `Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault()` in LINQ to EF.  Then I found this issue in code to find the most recently created item for a specified year from my DB

```
Private Function MostRecentItemByYear(year As Integer) As Item
    Dim jan1 As New Date(year, 1, 1)
    Dim dec31 As New Date(year, 12, 31)

    Return MyContext.Items.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i.DateCreated) _
                          .FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.DateCreated.HasValue AndAlso i.DateCreated >= jan1 AndAlso i.DateCreated <= dec31)
End Function
```

That code fails with

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyCompany.Domain.Models.Item'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

on the `Return MyContext ...` line.  However, If I move the lambda to a `Where` and call `FirstOrDefault` separately, it runs perfectly.

```
Private Function MostRecentItemByYear(year As Integer) As Item
    Dim jan1 As New Date(year, 1, 1)
    Dim dec31 As New Date(year, 12, 31)

    Return MyContext.Items.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i.DateCreated) _
                          .Where(Function(i) i.DateCreated.HasValue AndAlso i.DateCreated >= jan1 AndAlso i.DateCreated <= dec31) _
                          .FirstOrDefault()
End Function
```

Comment: Both queries should do the same. Rather strange. Also the exception message for the first query doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: That's what I thought too.  The call stack shows the exception occurs while translating the lambda to a SQL statement.